# How to disable table key in iTerm2

Tags: zsh, iterm2

I am using zsh and iTerm2. I always use the <kbd>Tab</kbd>-key when i want to autocomplete the command. But if there is no command to be autocompleted, the cursor will move forward which is not what i want.

So is there a way to disable the cursor that moves forward when no command can be autocompeleted, thanks.

Comment: When exactly? When the line is empty (you haven't typed anything yet) or when you type a command that doesn't exist?

Comment: @ahilsend : the former, but when i am typing **cd** command, the Tab key will cause one space after the path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour of <kbd>Tab</kbd> on an empty line can be configured by the zstyle [insert-tab](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-insert_002dtab_002c-completion-style):

```
zstyle ':completion:*' insert-tab <VAL>
```

where `<VAL>` can be

- *true* [*default*]: insert TAB character
- *false*: perform completion (completion list contains all commands)
- *pending* or *pending=val*: insert TAB character IF there is unprocessed input (pasting text), otherwise perform completion

So if you don't want it to insert a TAB, you can set it to false:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' insert-tab false
```